# php in_array search too broad, need array entry not just string value

Tags: php, arrays, string, search

I have the following code that looks through the category array and finds the existence of the string 'Events'. I want only it to trigger if there is NOT an array entry called "Events", something like for example 'News and Events' is fine. I'm sure it's a simple solution but I can't seem to find it. Any thoughts?

```
$cat_check = get_the_category_list(',');

$cat_check_array = explode(",",$cat_check);

if(!(in_array("Events", $cat_check_array, true))) { 
    //Do Something
}
```

Example of categories in $cat_check

```
$cat_check = "News and Events","Category 1","Category 2";
$cat_check = "Events";
```

The only thing I don't want this bit of code to trigger on is the existence of an array entry "Events", anything else like "News and Events" is perfectly fine.

Comment: what data does $cat_check have .. give some example

Comment: You probably have it backwards with the !.  It states IF `Events` is NOT in the array.  If `News and Events` is in the array but not just `Events` then the IF is true.

Comment: "I want only it to trigger if the WHOLE array entry is Events" does this mean you want only to do something if all elements contain the word Events?

Comment: Sorry I've updated my question. I had it backwards. Trigger ONLY if array does NOT include entry 'Events' specifically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`in_array()` does straight equality testing. It's not ever been capable of doing partial/substring matches. Bite the bullet and use a loop:

```
foreach($array as $haystack) {
   if (strpos($haystack, $needle) !== FALSE) {
      ... text is present
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Would [`array_reduce`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php) be what you are looking for?

```
function in_array_ext($value, $arr) {
   return array_reduce($arr, function ($carry, $item) use ($value) {
       return (strpos($item, $value) !== false) || $carry;
   }, false);
}


if (!in_array_ext("Events", $cat_check_array)) { 
   // Do something, "Events" does not present in the array values
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily perform that with the [preg_grep](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-grep.php) function :

> Return array entries that match the pattern

Code example :

```
$search = "Events"; // whatever you want
$result = preg_grep('~' . preg_quote($search, '~') . '~', $cat_check_array);
```

Here, we use the preg_quote function on the search variable to prevent uses of the ~ symbol